# functional composition in haskell

Tags: haskell, composition

How come I can't do

```
fst . fst (("Bob",12),10)
```

in Haskell?

```
:t fst . fst
Prelude> ((c,b),b1) -> c
```

Doesn't this make (("Bob",12),10) a good candidate for fst . fst since it's

```
(([Char],Integer),Integer)
```

Comment: Hint: It's parsed as `fst . (fst (("Bob",12),10))` whereas you want `(fst . fst) (("Bob",12),10)`.

Comment: @Vitus you really live up to your name as a Wunderkid (if your nick does stem from that movie) Thanks a lot :]

Comment: For the record, what was the actual GHCi error of your original line of code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The highest precedence in Haskell is function application or `f a`. So

```
fst . fst ((a, b), a)
```

is parsed as

```
fst . (fst ((a, b), a))
```

which is obviously nonsense. You can fix this with the `$` operator which is just function application with the lowest precedence, so `f $ a == f a`.

```
fst . fst $ ((a, b), a)
```

Or with some parens

```
(fst . fst) ((a, b), a)
```

Comment: What's more haskell-esque - the $ operator or parentheses?

Comment: @JaneDoe `$` in general